# How do I stop Windows server 2008 from going to sleep?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008

I have just upgraded my server 2003 to serrver 2008. As I write this, my site is available externally. If I were to try again in the morning,the site won't come up. However, if I log back onto the server or access the website from another computer on the network, it works just fine...again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in under control panel go to "hardware and sound"->"Power Options" then  just set the computer to sleep attribute to never

Answer (score 1):

Also if you set your computer to High Performance mode within the Power Options panel it defaults to Never.